# how to save image with real dimensions in SD card

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, dimensions

My app have some images in folder drawable,which size of all are 640*640 and user can save the images on his device. For saving, image is converted to bitmap and then it is saved.the  problem is  changing size  after saving:
1) after saving in folder drawable-hdpi, size  changed to 577*577
2) after saving in folder drawable-ldpi, size  changed to 1154*1154
3) after saving in folder drawable-mdpi, size  changed to 865*865
4) after saving in folder drawable-xdpi, size  changed to 433*433
5) after saving in folder drawable-xxhdpi, size  changed to 288*288
6) after saving in folder drawable it is changed to 865*865

How can i save image with real dimensions?
Thank you

Comment: You can provide your images in the `/assets` folder and then copy them to the SD card **without opening** them in an ImageView. Just a **binary file copy**. As you would do when dealing with a pre-filled database. By the way, you should fix your question, because I don't believe that images in **ldpi** density are bigger than images in **xxhdpi** density.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in Der Golem's comment, you can just place the images in the assets folder and do a binary file copy.

However if you need to load the bitmaps in their real dimensions for whatever reason, you can use this code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap yourBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.your_image, options);
```

Your images are probably being resized when you load them as bitmaps, based on the device dpi and the drawable folder you placed them in. Set *inScaled* to false to disable this.